# Connection timeout and socket timeout advice

Tags: sockets, http, networking, network-programming

I'm currently doing some research into connection and socket timeout settings but I'm fairly new to this stuff.

As a stab in the dark we are thinking of adding 40 seconds as a connection and sockettimeout when we run json over http calls to another server.

```
    httpConnectionManagerParams.setConnectionTimeout(40000);
    httpConnectionManagerParams.setSoTimeout(40000);
```

But really I don't know about how to understand what the ideal settings or best practices to use are. I would appreciate it if someone could give me some pointers on what to consider when or tips on how to come up with a good gestimate on these settings.

The sort of advice I'm looking for is something like ... 40 seconds is far too long because it might cause another issue.... or ... the higher you set this value the more chance you have of causing another isssue... or 40 seconds is not to high at all... or to work out an ideal figure multiply Y by T

thanks

---

### EDIT

Adding firebug trace of server call.
[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's no reason whatsoever why they should be equal. Considering each condition separately, you want to set it high enough that a timeout will indicate a genuine problem rather than just a temporary overload, and low enough that you maintain responsiveness of the application.

As a rule, 40 seconds is far too long for a connect timeout. I would view anything in double figures with suspicion. A server should be able to accept tens or hundreds of connections per second.

Read timeouts are a completely different matter. The 'correct' value, if there is such a thing, depends entirely on the average service time for the request and on its variance. As a starting point, you might want to set it to double the expected service time, or the average service time plus two or three standard deviations, depending entirely on your service level requirements and the performance of your server and its variance. There is no hard and fast rule about this. Many contractual service level agreements (SLAs) specify a 'normal' response time of two seconds, which may inform your deliberations. But it's your decision.

Comment: excellent answer and it is leading me down the right track to make some infromed decisions. The connection timeout should be single figures but the socket timeout which is time spent waiting for a response once at the server varies depending on the application. I'm about to change my post above to include a trace of the worst performing service call on the remote server. From this trace the connection time looks to be very quick but the socket repsonse time is 33.29 seconds so as a guesstimate if I set the so timeout to 45 seconds I think that makes sense. Am I heading down the right track?

Comment: Sounds like a decent starting point, but it depends on the variance of the service times. I would also be rather concerned about a service whose average response time is 30 seconds. I'd look to improve that first, to well under ten seconds.

Comment: thanks... your a legend. It's funny how I've been a java web programmer for so long but have never had to look at this sort of stuff until now. It's only come up because we have an old application server which is getting hung threads when the service call never comes back because of network latency or issues at the host where the services are hosted on.

Comment: Well just to point out that connect timeouts have nothing to do with that.

Comment: Maybe not for a connection timeout but for a so timeout it does right?

Comment: flawless answer!